# Checking input of a method if it exists on a list Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, oop

```
@dataclass
class Product:
    name: str
    quantity: int 
    price: float

class Transaction:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mapDict = {}
        self.mapVal = []
    
    def add_item(self, name, quantity, price):
        res = name not in self.mapVal
        if res:
            self.mapDict[len(self.mapVal)] = Product(name, quantity, price)
            self.mapVal.append(name)
        return res
    
    def check_if_not_exists(self, name):
        if name not in self.mapVal:
            return name
        else:
            raise Exception("Name already exists. Update instead?")
```

I try to replace `res = name not in self.mapVal` line in `add_item()` by creating `check_if_not_exists()` so I can use it later for different method such as `update_name() or remove_item()`.
I know using `res = self.check_if_not_exists(name)` would do the job, but is there a better way?

Comment: How do you define "better"?

Comment: Prolly a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `True` or `False` in `check_if_not_exists`.

```
def add_item(self, name, quantity, price):
    product_doesnt_exists = self.check_if_not_exists(name)
    if product_doesnt_exists:
        self.mapDict[len(self.mapVal)] = Product(name, quantity, price)
        self.mapVal.append(name)
        return True
    else:
        return False  # or raise Exception('Product already exists')


def check_if_not_exists(self, name):
    if name not in self.mapVal:
        return False
    else:
        raise True
```

I suggest you to use `set` instead of `list` for `mapVal` attribute, because it's faster to check if an element exists in a `set` than in a `list`.

I suggest you to rename your variables and methods. `mapDict` and `mapVal` are not good names, instead you can use `products` and `product_names` or something like that. `add_item` and `check_if_not_exists` are not good names, instead you can use `add_product` and `product_exists` or something like that.

```
class Transaction:

    def __init__(self):
        self.products = {}
        self.product_names = []

    def add_item(self, name, quantity, price):
        product_exists = self.product_exists(name)
        if product_exists:
            return False
        else:
            self.products[len(self.product_names)] = Product(name, quantity, price)
            self.product_names.append(name)
            return True

    def product_exists(self, name):
        if name in self.product_names:
            return True
        else:
            raise False
```

You can remove product_names attribute and use products.keys() instead, and set product names as keys in products dictionary.

```
class Transaction:

    def __init__(self):
        self.products = {}

    def add_item(self, name, quantity, price):
        product_exists = self.product_exists(name)
        if product_exists:
            return False
        else:
            self.products[name] = Product(name, quantity, price)
            return True

    def product_exists(self, name):
        return name in self.products.keys()
```